# How do I add newlines when editing a post body via the API?

Tags: support, api, python, write-access, posts

I am editing the tags of a question via the API, and to do that you have to pass the body and title etc.

I can get the Markdown or HTML from the API but I can't see how to send it back formatted properly.

[These revisions](https://askubuntu.com/posts/374644/revisions) pretty much show what I've tried:

- `\n\r`. [Didn't work (rev 4)](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/374644/4).
- `<br><br>`, as given by the API Markdown. [Didn't work (rev 6)](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/374644/6).
- `<p>...</p>`, as given by the API HTML. [Works (rev 8)](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/374644/8), but [boy does that question Markdown look ugly](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/f3a07b98-ec53-41e5-a5da-46d26c1debec/view-source).
- `designed%20for%20the%20following%20` - URL encode. [Didn't work (rev 9)](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/374644/9).
- `%0A%0A` replacing `\n\r`. [Didn't work (rev 12)](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/374644/12).

So how do I edit it neatly?

---

Even direct copy / paste from the [source page](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/0a1db3fa-be07-403a-8cec-049c6e9f50ea/view-source#) into the [body box](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/edit-question#) gives [bad results](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/374644/20).

Comment: Sequence matters. It should be `\r\n` and the string should have the hex bytes 0x0D, 0x0A (before form encoding). Make sure you escape (or don't) the `\\`s properly for whatever language you are using.

Comment: @BrockAdams so i should be giving `\\\r\\\\n` instead?

Comment: The form encoded string that your app sends should contain `%0D%0A` bits.  If it has `%250D%250A`, you're miss/over encoding. What language are you using?  For most languages, it's just `\r\n` in a plain ASCII string.

Comment: @BrockAdams Python. The API is saying I'm calling it wrong now, but when I use the body box on the api page, it gives messy code: http://askubuntu.com/revisions/374644/22

Comment: @BrockAdams thanks :) Worked it out now - I was using a get request. `\r\n` works perfectly!

Comment: btw @Tim you could use [The API Sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51812/the-api-sandbox) for editing... Or the [Formatting Sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I did consider it, but I wanted to keep it getting the questions from the search, so it had to be one that came up there. Will do in the future!

Comment: @Tim no problem :) just a suggestion! (it's good the load-of-edits community-wiki conversion has gone now! :)

Comment: You should post an answer here (or delete this Q). Include an example of the Python code you ended up using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\r\n` issue was solved when I changed to a `POST` request.

But, since I was retagging questions (didn't really need to change the body, just resend it), I ended up using the `body_markdown`, encoded with `HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape()`

```python
body_markdown = str(HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape(question_data['items'][0]['body_markdown']))
```

And then sending it with:

```python
response = requests.post('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/'+str(q_id)+'/edit',
      data={'body': body_markdown,
            'comment': 'removed '+tag+' tag',
            'tags': ' '.join(tags),
            'title': title,
            'access_token': token,
            'site': site,
            'key': key
            }
        )
```